# The use of the verb "go" in the sense of getting to places without mentioning the places

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Tell me please if the followig sentence sounds natural.

> I like **going** by bus.

What I am trying to say is that I like to go to some places, such as libraries, stores, post offices etc, using the bus. Would a native English speaker ever say something like that?

Comment: Yep, all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a good reply to a question:

> How do you usually get to the library?

answer:

> I like going by bus.

or

> what's your favorite way to get to the shopping mall?

answer:

> I like going by bus.

So, it's a valid answer...  However, would it make sense to say that, out of the blue, without mentioning any destination?  Probably what you mean to say is:

- "Generally, I enjoy travelling by bus."
- "I like riding the bus."
- "The bus is the best way to get around."
- "Usually I ride the bus, (whenever I go someplace)." etc.

The original sentence "I like going by bus" should have a reference to *where* you are going.